# Disable a cell in WPF datagrid when combo value is set to a value - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` column and I need to enable or disable a checkbox cell in another column but my code doesn't appear to work.

I have the following code defining my combo column:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Location"
 SelectedValueBinding="{Binding LocationId, Mode=TwoWay}"
 SelectedValuePath="LocationId"
 DisplayMemberPath="LocationText"
 TextBinding="{Binding Location, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

and this is the code for my checkbox column:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" 
 Binding="{Binding IsActive}">
   <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
       <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLineItem.Location}" 
          Value="01">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>                                        
       </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
  </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

I've added a DataTrigger to try to detect when the Location field changes to 01, and based on that I'm trying to disable the checkbox cell for in the selected row, but it doesn't work.

I also need to check/uncheck the combo based on other values.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

**UPDATE 1:**

Ok, I've made some progress (by fluke!) where now my triggers are kicking in but for some reason, whenever I change the location in my drop down for the selected cell, it changes the value for all the rows to that same value.

Here's my full code for the dropdown column:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Location"
    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding DataContext.SelectedLineItem.SelectedLocation, 
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
    Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="LocationId"
                        DisplayMemberPath="LocationText"
                        TextBinding="{Binding Location, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.Locations, 
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.Locations, 
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
             AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding DataContext.SelectedLocation, 
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
             AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
            <EventSetter Event="KeyUp" Handler="LocationColumn_KeyUp"></EventSetter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="true" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

And here is the full code for my checkbox column (Don't worry about what the triggers do - they are test triggers):

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding IsActive}">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationId}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="01" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="02" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="03" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Can anyone figure out why all my rows are now being set when I change a value in a combo?

Thanks.

Comment: The datacontext for that binding may not be what you think it is; does it work with `RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I've updated my answer. Got further but still not 100% there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Freeman for pointing in the right direction.

I ended up figuring it out and the only way I managed to fully get it to work was a combination of setting properties in XAML and applying some basic logic in my ViewModel.

Here's the full explanation:

I have a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` which is binded to my `SelectionLocation` property and belong to my row ViewModel

```
get { return this._selectedLocation; }
set { Set(() => SelectedLocation, ref this._selectedLocation, value); }
```

Now regarding the binding in XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Location"
    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedLocation, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="LocationId"
    DisplayMemberPath="LocationText">
```

This was my first problem as whenever I selected an item from the combo, it didn't call/trigger the setter part of my SelectedLocation ViewModel. This was fixed by adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Warehouse"
    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedLocation, Mode=TwoWay,
                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectedValuePath="LocationId"
    DisplayMemberPath="LocationText">
```

Regarding the checkbox column, the XAML was defined as:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Again, when checking and unchecking my checkbox, it didn't trigger the setter of my IsActive property which belong to the same ViewModel as 'SelectedLocation' property.

To fix this problem I ended up adding the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay, 
     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Now that the binding issues with the Combo and the checkbox columns are sorted, one thing remained. Conditional selection. This was sorted by using a combination of `DataTrigger` in XAML and code in my ViewModel.

The XAML took care of enabling/disabling the checkbox as on the selection from the SelectedLocation:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay, 
     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="01" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="02" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="03" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

And in my ViewModel, whenever the SelectedLocation setter is triggered, it now applies the same rule i.e. checking if location is 01, 02 or 03 and it will set my IsActive property and therefore select/unselect the checkbox:

```
public LocationViewModel SelectedLocation
{
    get { return this._selectedLocation; }
    set
    {
        Set(() => SelectedLocation, ref this._selectedLocation, value);
        if (this._selectedLocation.LocationText == "01")
            this.IsActive = false;
        else if (this._selectedLocation.LocationText == "02")
            this.IsActive = true;
        else if (this._selectedLocation.LocationText == "03")
        {
            this.IsActive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is obviously not ideal but it is working exactly as expected. The ideal solution would have been to have `IsChecked` set to true or false based on a condition in XAML as such:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="02" >
<Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
</DataTrigger>
```

But for whatever reason, when I use this method, it will trigger the `IsActive` setter when I check the checkbox manually, but it will not trigger it based on the trigger rules, thus making this property useless which I cannot have.

Anyway, I think that's it. Hope this helps other.

**UPDATE**

I had to post an update as to my surprise, while the checkbox is disabled using

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay, 
     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="01" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="02" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="03" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

It is only temporarily disabled. Double clicking on the cell actually enables the cell and then re-enables the checkbox! Totally pointless to let you disable a checkbox to then re-enable it when the cell goes in edit mode!!!

Anyway, luckily, there is a work around which is to disable the cell instead of the checkbox. This can be achieved by using the `CellStyle` instead of the `ElementStyle`:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="01" >
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="02" >
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="03" >
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding your checkbox to SelectedLineItem.Location. But i can see that this property is not bound anywhere to the combo box. You have bound your combobox's TextBinding to 'Location'. Try changing it to SelectedILineItem.Location as well. Then checkbox will be bound to the typed value in combobox.

If you would like to enable/disable checkbox depending on the combobox's selected value, either you should bind your combobox's SelectedValuePath to this property or change your checkbox binding to SelectedItem.LocationId and trigger condition, to match the binding of combo box.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly I think this you can try this way. I binded a list of countries in a combo box and based on the selection of some value I disabled the other column.

The Xaml code looks like

```
<Window.Resources>
        <staticData:CountryList x:Key="CountryList"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SampleList}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Countries" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedCountry}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Height="22" Grid.Row="0"
                                        ItemsSource="{StaticResource CountryList}"
                                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry}">
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <!-- Inputs -->
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="SizeToCells" Header="Inputs" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Input}" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedCountry}" Value="UK">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Viewmodel has

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private List<SampleData> sampleList;

        public List<SampleData> SampleList
        {
            get { return sampleList; }
            set { Set(ref sampleList, value); }
        }

        private Country selectedItem;

        public Country SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }
            set { selectedItem = value; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Country> countries;

        public ObservableCollection<Country> CountriesList
        {
            get { return countries; }
            set { this.Set(ref countries, value); }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            CountriesList = new ObservableCollection<Country> { new Country { Id = 1, Name = "India" }, new Country { Id = 1, Name = "Australia" } };

            SampleList = new List<SampleData>
            {
                new SampleData
                {
                    Input = "shan", RowNum = 3, SelectedCountry = "India"
                },

                new SampleData
                {
                    Input = "raj", RowNum = 1, SelectedCountry =  "India"
                },

                new SampleData
                {
                    Input = "sfk", RowNum = 9,  SelectedCountry =  "India"
                },

                new SampleData
                {
                    Input = "ShanSfk", RowNum = 7,  SelectedCountry =  "India"
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

and the list is

```
  public class CountryList : List<string>
    {
        public CountryList()
        {
            this.Add("India");
            this.Add("Australia");
            this.Add("UK");
        }
    }
```

Based on the selection of country in combo box the cell is enabled or disabled.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide such a detailed sample, but you were using a different control type for the combo column, and while I tried to fit in what you had, I ended up spending more time trying to figure out this problem. I've updated my answer with more information if that's of any help.